# cannot run Selenium Ruby Webdriver on IE9 browser

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I got the error below when trying to run a Selenium Ruby Webdriver
script on IE9 browser, the browser is not launched and below error
displayed:

```
  Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find standalone executable
  . Please download the IEDriverServer from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/down
  loads/list and place the executable on your PATH.

 Below are lines of code that I have tried:

  browser=Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie
  @driver.get CONFIG['url']
```

Please guide me if I need to do more steps on this case to be able to run scripts on IE9 browser with Ruby Selenium Webdriver. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error log is self-explanatory.  Going forward IEDriver has to be downloaded separately, as you might be doing for chromedriver till now.
A good explanation by the creator [here](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.in/2012_11_01_archive.html) .  You can download the driver zip from the link in the error log and add it to your PATH.  Read more @ [IEDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)